# django CBV doesnt pagginate with editing context

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

View down below should show the tasks for the logged user but when I paginate the tasks I got

`Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.`

how should I filter the context to avoid the error for pagination?

```
class TaskList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Task
    context_object_name = 'tasks'
    template_name = 'TaskList.html'
    paginate_by = 2

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tasks'] = context['tasks'].filter(user=self.request.user)

        return context
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `get_queryset()` for filtering objects in `ListView`:

```py
def get_queryset(self):  # noqa: D102
    queryset = super().get_queryset()
    return queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

The filtering in `get_queryset()` method should fix the issue - also remove `get_context_data()` method overload, it's not neccessary.

Comment: Is there a way to access the http request in main CBV? to change the queryset attr and also change the number of pagination  with request?

Comment: Yes, by overriding `get_paginate_by()` method, also you can access request by using `self.request`, the same way it's in code that I posted for you.